# Send array of data to SQL Server Stored Procedure in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlsrv

I have below two tables in an SQL Server database:

**invoices table**

```
ID    | INVOICE_NO |
--------------------
1     | 1000000001 |
2     | 1000000002 |
3     | 1000000003 |
```

**invoice_details table**

```
ID    | INVOICE_ID | DESCRIPTION | AMOUNT |
-------------------------------------------
1     | 1          | Electricity | 3500.00|
2     | 1          | Telephone   |  750.00|
3     | 2          | Car Service | 6500.00|
4     | 2          | Other       | 1500.00|
```

I want to export above details to an SQL Server Stored Procedure using PHP script. When sending, I want to select first row from `invoices` table and related two rows from `invoice_details` table (Like wise). So `invoice_details` must be in a array or something.

**My problems are;**

1. How to make SQL Server Stored Procedure to get this done?
2. How to send these details (Can I use array to send invoice details together with invoice data)?

Please guide if anyone have an idea about this.

Comment: Google Table Valued Parameter

Comment: @DaleK There is no way to send TVP from php.

Comment: It's not elegant, but... you could encode the invoice_details data as XML and provide to the stored procedure as a `@details xml` parameter, shredding it inside the proc to insert into the invoice_details table. On newer versions of SQL Server you could also encode as JSON and send as `@details nvarchar(max)`. In fact if you're going to that trouble you could send the entire batch as XML or JSON.

Comment: @LahiruTM JSON is a good option here. Which driver do you use to connect to SQL Server and what is the SQL Server version?

Comment: @Zhorov SQL Server 2008, SQL_SRV

Answer (score 0):

According to the idea given by @AlwaysLearning, I was able to resolve my problem using XML.

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[insert_xml_data]
(
    @details AS XML = '
    <details>
        <invoice_details>
            <line_id>3</line_id>
            <account_code>5000</account_code>
            <description>Other purchases</description>
            <amount>15250.00</amount>
        </invoice_details>
    </details>
    ';
)
As

BEGIN
    
    INSERT INTO xml_data (account_code,description,amount)
        SELECT  
    t1.c.value('account_code[1]','varchar(100)') As account_code, 
    t1.c.value('description[1]','varchar(50)') as description, 
    t1.c.value('amount[1]','varchar(50)') as amount,
    FROM @details.nodes('/details/invoice_details') t1(c)
END
```